# Emscripten gives an error on simple make. OSX

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile, emscripten

I'm trying to build something with Emscripten. So far, I've got the tools installed, like Python etc. I've created a simple makefile:

```
engine:
    ../engine/math/Matrix3x3.cpp\
```

This file contains only arrhythmic C++ code in some classes and no includes so I thought I'd start with this one. If I run emmake or emconfigure I get these errors:

```
$ /bin/sh ../../emscripen/emscripten/1.21.0/emmake make $PWD/engine.mk
...
```

**Update**: Ok, I shouldn't have run it with /bin/sh in front of the command after all.

But then I'm back to where I started. Somehow, I am unable to create even the simplest of simple makefiles. These are my contents:

```
engine:
    gcc Matrix3x3.cpp
```

I've moved all files locally so there are no path mixups. This is the command I'm running: (switched back to normal make just to get a grasp at how makefiles work)

```
make $PWD/engine.mk engine
```

This is the output:

```
$ make engine.mk engine
make: Nothing to be done for `engine.mk'.
make: *** No rule to make target `engine'.  Stop.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Update: Ok, I shouldn't have run it with /bin/sh in front of the command after all. But then I'm back to where I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Ok, so I finally found out that the makefile should be preceded with the -f flag.

```
make -f $PWD/engine.mk engine
```